# Unit Testing without DI

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc

I am starting a small ASP.NET MVC project, each task on the board must come with unit tests. The project is small, just a few pages with not that much processing, so I decided not to implement DI. My thoughts being DI is for larger projects with dependency graphs.

However, now I am writing tests it has made me realise testing is more difficult. There is no constructor injection going on, so mocking these objects being used by the controller actions is proving troublesome.

If there are objects being instantiated on the action due to lack of contructor injection how can you mock them to test?

Comment: Why don't you use constructor injection? That gives you 90% of the DI benefits for virtually no work.

Comment: Well, in retrospect I would probably set up a DI container and use that. I had it in my head that DI setup was not worth the time on small projects. I am just looking to see if there is an alternative without implementing one (reversing the decision)

Comment: Try Microsoft Shims.

Comment: I find that fighting against the DI pattern is a losing battle when writing unit tests.  You wind-up with crazy schemes or 3rd-party tools that are harder than simple constructor injection

Comment: I agree with @MobyDisk... There are alternatives, and they're all worse than simple DI. Shims is a perfect example.

Comment: It's not too late to rework the application to introduce DI. The time taken will easily be recouped by spending less time trying to shoe-horn tests into a badly designed system.

Comment: I think a system can not use DI and not be badly designed. However, I think it may be worth adding it so I can properly test my controllers.

Comment: My initial thought was wasted resources with items being instantiated that may not be used by the method being called but I do agree the effect it has on unit testing is too great. Looks like I am backtracking. Thanks all for input

Comment: If you donot want to use ioc/di because of the overhead/learning required by a di container you can start with [poor-mans-dependency-injection](https://software2cents.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/poor-mans-dependency-injection/) that does not need a container.

Comment: ***DI != IoC Container***. You can ctor inject your dependencies without a fancy framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a question: does this look like DI?

```
public class MyCar
{
    private IEngine _engine;

    public MyCar(IEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }

    public MyCar()
        : this(new MyV8Engine())
    {

    }
}
```

It should, because it IS DI. Dependency Injection is about injecting a dependency into an object, instead of placing the burden of new'ing up or finding the dependency on the object that requires it. **DI is not about using a framework, it is a design pattern that solves an issue**.

It is very valid for small applications to use constructor-based injection and new'ing up objects in default constructors. The reason you don't see this as an example of DI is because often times your dependency graph quickly becomes very big and unwieldy and the move to a DI framework rapidly becomes advantageous as your application grows.

Answer (score 3):

> If there are objects being instantiated on the action due to lack of contructor injection how can you mock them to test?

You can refactor your code to encapsulate all code that should be mocked away into a 
seperate protected methods and then use [partial-mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx) to replace that logic.

Example (in java)

Original

```
protected void moveFiles(File[] destFiles, File[] sourceFiles) {
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < fileCount) {
        File sourceFile = sourceFiles[pos];
        File destFile = destFiles[pos];

        // do some processing. i.e. rename destFile if it already exists.

        // do the copy. the test should not execute this
        sourceFile.renameTo(destFile)
        pos++;
    }
}
```

refactored:

```
protected void moveFiles(File[] destFiles, File[] sourceFiles) {
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < fileCount) {
        File sourceFile = sourceFiles[pos];
        File destFile = destFiles[pos];

        // do some processing. i.e. rename destFile if it already exists.
        osFileMove(destFile, sourceFile);
        pos++;
    }
}

/** can be replaced by mock/stub in unittests */
protected boolean osFileMove(File destFile, File sourceFile) {
    return sourceFile.renameTo(destFile);
}
```

in the test you can replace `osFileMove` with a fake (example uses java  org.mockito.Mockito)

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

FileCommands sut;
@Before
public void setup() {
    sut = spy(new FileCommands());
    doReturn(true).when(sut).osCreateDirIfNeccessary(any(File.class));
    doReturn(true).when(sut).osFileCopy(any(File.class), any(File.class));
    doReturn(true).when(sut).osFileMove(any(File.class), any(File.class));
    doReturn(true).when(sut).osDeleteFile(any(File.class));
}
```

If you later decide to use ioc you can move the os-spcific file operations `osxXXXX` into a seperate class plus an interface